# Testing Hibernate with Spring and asynchronous code

Tags: spring, hibernate, asynchronous

I have an event-driven framework with event handlers that might perform a write in a DB, through Hibernate. I would need to write integration tests, but I have no idea on how one can make it.

In fact, when one condition occurs, an event handler is triggered in a different thread, and this writes on the DB. How can I say that that write operation should be rolled back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make some asynchronous tests, take a look at [Awaitility](http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/).

I have used it, and it does the job quite well :)

But if you want to rollback your write operations, you'll have to get the transaction in the proper thread.

Comment: So a Spring transactional test will automatically rollback all the operations executed in its thread right?

Comment: I think that if your Spring test launches another thread with its own transaction, this test will not be able to do the rollback. You have to figure out how to get the Hibernate session attached to the thread.